# Validate nested object only if parent is present

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have a request body looking something like this:

```
{
    "folder": { "value": "testFolder", "operator": "=" },
    "name": { "value": "5456", "operator": "contains" }
}
```

The body of the request is not required though. How can I validate that `value` and `operator` is present for each object if `body` is present?

**Edit**: 
Forgot to mention that I want to use `Joi Validator`. The problem I'm running into is with something like this:

```
body: Joi.object().keys({
    $key: Joi.object().keys({ <-- since the $key placeholder is unique
        value: Joi.string().required(),
        operator: Joi.string().required()
    })
})
```

What should I use there?

Comment: You can use express-validator for it if you are using express. https://express-validator.github.io/docs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging in the documentation and forums, this solution works for me. Might be helpful for someone:

```
body: Joi.object().pattern(
  Joi.string(),
  Joi.object().keys({
    value: Joi.string().required(),
    operator: Joi.string().required()
  })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if body exists (object, empty-or-not), if exists then start to loop through checking its objects (using a function, cleaner than ifs), if don't matches, then you return false, otherwise true.

Eg.:

```
const ifHaveItemValidateBody = function(body) {
    if (!body) return false;

    for (let k in body) {
        const item = body[k];
        if ((!(item && item.value && item.operator))) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
};
```

---

In your server-entry:

```
if (body && !ifHaveItemValidateBody(body) {
    /* do something */
}
```